# Rotate Button for HMD in AFrame/Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr, 360-degrees

Using the "hmd-controls" (https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/controls/hmd-controls.js) from A-frame's "universal-controls", I am looking to use a rotate button with the hmd camera and not lose the sensor movement controls.

For desktops I was able to adjust the reference object `this.yaw.rotation.y` and the controls would use the adjusted rotation. The hmd-controls, however, use the device's absolute position instead of a reference object. (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/1853#r77108040)

Without a reference object, it seems, I can adjust the camera or adjust the hmd.

When I change the rotation of the hmd's camera, the rotation snaps back when the hmd-controls update. `vrControls.update();`

When I adjust anything in `.poseSensor_.` called using `vrControls.getVRDisplay()` I effectively break the controls.

I have not, yet, been able to locate a variable for the hmd that handles its 'global' rotation and that is not overwritten on `vrControls.update();`

Does anyone know if there is a variable that can be adjusted to produce the desired effect or have any ideas for a possible work around or alternative approach?

I have tried the wrap the camera in another entity and rotate, but this method causes an issue where the camera position is rotated around the 0,0,0 position instead of the current position; or other control issues.

Any thoughts?